# Find the first and second moments of a distribution of order statistics?

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

I'm not totally sure how to even word this question, but I need to find the first and second moments of two variables, $M$ and $N$ as defined by:

$M=\min(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ and $N=\max(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ where $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,1)$.

Here's what we have:

$F_N(m)=1-(1-F_X(m))^n$

$f_N(m)=n(1-F_X(m))^{n-1}f_X(m))$

$F_M(m)=F_x(m)^n$

$f_M(m)=nF_X(m)^{n-1}f_X(m)$

I'm a little stuck actually computing the expectations, though. By definition, I know

$E[X^k]=\int_{0}^{1}x^kf_X(x)dx$,

But I'm getting really confused by the actual computation for my specific purposes of calculating $E[M], E[M^2], E[N], E[N^2]$. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were given\taught the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), then, since you know the density of $M$ (the minimum),
\begin{align*}
E[M] &= \int_0^1 mf_M(m)\,dm\\
&=\int_0^1m\cdot n(1-m)^{n-1}\,dm\\
&=n \int_0^1\cdot m^{2-1}(1-m)^{n-1}\,dm\\
&=n B(2,n)\\
&=n \cdot\frac{(2-1)!(n-1)!}{(2+n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, 
\begin{align*}
E[M^2] &= \int_0^1m^2f_M(m)\,dm\\
&=\int_0^1m^2\cdot n(1-m)^{n-1}\,dm\\
&=n \int_0^1m^{3-1}(1-m)^{n-1}\,dm\\
&=nB(3,n)\\
&=n\cdot\frac{(3-1)!(n-1)!}{(3+n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{2!n!}{(n+2)!}\\
&=\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align*}
You can verify that
$$\text{Var}[M] = E[X^2]-\{E[X]\}^2 = \frac{n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}.$$

This will work $N$ also.

Comment: So the moments of $M$ and $N$ are the same?

Comment: @Taylor No, $E[N] = \frac{n}{n+1}$.

Comment: Is the other answer on this page wrong, then?

Comment: @Taylor Not completely. We actually calculated the same thing. I did not proofread that person's work until a moment ago. But it is right, if you switch the $N$ to an $M$.

Comment: @Taylor You will learn that distribution of $M$ follows a [$\text{Beta}(1,n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), so that is how I checked my work. Since its properties are know, then I can check its expectation and variance.

Comment: Oh!! I saw the problem!! I change the letters on the other link!! I put $M$ for the max and $N$ for the min. Sorry @Taylor. Do you let me edit YOUR question in the other post in order to agree with all the notation I'm using? (I ask you edit your post because it is easier than change notation in all that I wrote)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628497/find-the-joint-distribution-of-the-continuous-order-statistics) I gave you explicitely forms of each distribution.

For $N$:

$\begin{eqnarray}E[N]&=&\int_0^1nx(1-x)^{n-1}dx\\
&=&\frac{n}{n^2+n}\\
&=&\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}$

$\begin{eqnarray}E[N^2]&=&\int_0^1nx^2(1-x)^{n-1}dx\\
&=&\frac{2n}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=&\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{eqnarray}$

Can you do for $M$?

**Hint** $$E[M]=\int_0^1 {n\cdot x\cdot x^{n-1}} dx\mbox{ and }E[M^2]=\int_0^1 {n\cdot x^2\cdot x^{n-1}} dx$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining the subscripts in the explicit forms?

Comment: It means indicator functions: $1_{A}(t)=1$ if $t\in A$ and $0$ in other case, and have nice properties: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoints, then $(f(x)1_A(x)+g(x)1_B(x))^n=f(x)^n1_A(x)+g(x)^n1_B(x)$. In particular $[x1_{A}(x)]^n=x^n1_{A}(x)$ (that is, the exponents don't affect the indicator function)

Comment: Is that necessary?

Comment: If $Z\in U(0,1)$, then $f_Z(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{b-a}&\mbox{if }z\in[a,b]\\0&\mbox{i.o.c.}\end{array}\right.$, ok. But using indicator functions it writes only like $f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{b-a}1_{[a,b]}(z)$. Then, a first use is compact notations.

Comment: I calculated $E[M]=\frac{n}{2}$ and $E[M^{2}]=\frac{n}{3}$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, they are not the answers

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the density functions are.

Comment: The density functions are the $f$. The cumulative are the $F$

Comment: @sinbadh I think you got $M$ and $N$ mixed up. You just calculated $E[M]$, not $E[N]$.

Comment: @probablyme i have an eyes problem, and i'm not sure. I believe you change $M$ and $N$.

Comment: @sinbadh I think you know that $M$ is the minimum and so the distribution of $M$ is Beta$(1,n)$. The expectation you calculated is of a Beta$(1,n)$ distribution.

Comment: Yes @problamy. In a comment to your answer I explain my error. Thanks